# OSStatus error 1685348671 AVAudioPlayer

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, alamofire, avaudioplayer

I'm trying to download mp3 file with Alamofire and save it to desired location. Then, from that location, I'm trying to play that file, but it gives me an error.

This is download function

```
func downloadSong(song: Song, completion: @escaping(Bool) -> ()) {

        var headers: HTTPHeaders = [:]

        if let authorizationHeader = Request.authorizationHeader(user: Constants.authName, password: Constants.authKey) {
            headers[authorizationHeader.key] = authorizationHeader.value
        }

        let destination: DownloadRequest.DownloadFileDestination = { _, _ in
            let documentsURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
            let fileURL = documentsURL.appendingPathComponent("\(song.getID()).mp3")

            return (fileURL, [.removePreviousFile, .createIntermediateDirectories])
        }

        Alamofire.download(APIEndpoint.Song(id: song.getID(), token: self.authToken!).path(), method: .get, headers: headers, to: destination).response { (response) in
            if response.error == nil, let filePath = response.destinationURL?.path {
                print(filePath)
                completion(true)
            } else {
                completion(false)
            }
        }

    }
```

This is a playback function

```
func playSong() {

        guard let songs = currentPlaylist?.getSongs() else { return }

        let song = songs[0]

        let documentsDirectoryURL =  FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!

        let destinationUrl = documentsDirectoryURL.appendingPathComponent("\(song.getID()).mp3")
        print(destinationUrl)

        if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: destinationUrl.path) {
            print("The file already exists at path")

            do {
                try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
                try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)

                player! = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: destinationUrl, fileTypeHint: AVFileTypeMPEGLayer3)

                player!.play()
            } catch let error as NSError {
                print("error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }

    }
```

I would like to know the best practice of downloading the file and saving it and then playing it.

Comment: [The error code sounds like theres something wrong with the file.](https://www.osstatus.com/search/results?platform=all&framework=all&search=1685348671)

Comment: Oh, thank you, I did not know about this website! So, how should I download the file with Alamofire and save it as mp3 file, or how to load the file from the destination url?

Comment: Nothing in your code looks wrong to me. Make sure that the file is a valid mp3 and not like a 404 page or something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found out, that I've entered the wrong API url, so it gave me invalid file which is not playable.

EDIT:

The file from the backend was not a valid MP3 audio file, that's why the error occurred.

Comment: this is not helpful for others, please specify what exactly was wrong, or this isn't acceptable answer.

Comment: This answer is useful now: i have the same error and likely the data were not saved properly